# C++ trying to find a suitable design pattern for a complex problem regarding CRTP and dependency

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, crtp

Let's consider the following example:

(`Function<FunctionType>` is just a class that applies some function specified by the enum `FunctionType`)

```
template<FunctionType funcType>
class System {
public:
    void doEverything() {
        //Iterate through every module in sequence and call doSomething()
    }
    
    void undoEverything() {
        //Iterate through every module in sequence and call undoSomething()
    }

    template<class Derived>
    void add(GenericModule<Derived>& module) {
        //Add module to list
    }
};

template<class Derived>
class GenericModule {
private:
    Derived* crtp = static_cast<Derived*>(this);
    
public:

    void doSomething() {
        crtp->doSomething();
    }
    
    void undoSomething() {
        crtp->undoSomething();
    }
    
};

template<FunctionType funcType, int param>
class ModuleA : public GenericModule<ModuleA<funcType, param>> {
private:
        Function<funcType> func;
public:
        
        void doSomething() {
            std::cout << param+1 << "\n";
        }
        
        void undoSomething() {
            std::cout << func.doFunction(param) << "\n";
        }
};

template<FunctionType funcType, int param1, int param2>
class ModuleB : public GenericModule<ModuleB<funcType, param1, param2>> {
private:
    Function<funcType> func;
public:
    
    void doSomething() {
        std::cout << param1 + param2 << "\n";
    }
    
    void undoSomething() {
        std::cout << func.doFunction(param1+param2) << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    System<FUNC1> system;
    ModuleA<FUNC1, 1> m1;
    ModuleB<FUNC1, 1, 2> m2;
    
    system.add(m1);
    system.add(m2);
    system.doEverything();
    system.undoEverything();
}
```

**Goal:**
The goal with this is to create multiple modules which together make up a "system" so that with only one call to `doEverything()` or `undoEverything()` all their respective functions can be executed in sequence. Important is that all modules of a system share the same `FunctionType` argument specified in the `system` template.
I intentionally used CRTP as this has to be highly efficient and thus any use of virtual functions is discouraged.

My approach was to use CRTP to create a common interface `GenericModule` from which all modules can be called. I thought the observer pattern might be suitable to register any module in `system`.

**Problems:**

1. How can I implement the add/register functionality in `system`? I'm thinking about a heterogeneous container that stores any type of `GenericModule` or something similar. It's important that this technique has as little overhead as possible which is certainly going to be difficult to implement. I'd also consider a complete re-design of this functionality as this might not be optimal.
2. The `FunctionType` argument is only relevant to the `System` class and not to a particular module. The module still needs this argument for it's functionality and due to efficiency reasons it has to be defined as a template argument so it can be used in a constexpr context. But because this argument is already set in the `System` class and all it's modules share the same value it's highly redundant for it to be redefined on every instantation of a module.
   I want to instantiate each module in the context of it's system so that the `FunctionType` argument doesn't have to be redefined every single time. In combination with that I't might even be possible that `System` automatically adds/registers the module when it's instantiated in it's context.

I have no clue how I could implement all these afromentioned things and that's why I'm asking you.

**Update:** I just had an idea on how I could solve the first problem. Instead of storing each module in the `System` class I could just put a reference to the next module as a member variable in the previous module. But I have not yet figured out how I could set it's type at compile time.

Comment: `System` could store two `std::vector<std::function<void()>>`. Then `add` would look like this: `template<typename Module> void add(Module& module) { doVector.push_back([&module]() { module.doSomething(); }); /* Similarly for undo */}` Not sure this would be more efficient than a virtual call (which is pretty cheap - have you actually measured it and determined it to be a bottleneck?). This approach doesn't require nor benefit from `GenericModule` (which isn't going to help, I suspect; I'm not sure why you introduced it in the first place).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm actually considering this method at the moment but I still see it as pretty inefficient. The thing is that in my actual code there are many modules and the System functions are called several thousand to million times which makes even the small inefficiencies have a much bigger impact. I already kinda recognized that my example inherently uses dynamic polymorphism so I have to rewrite it a little bit

Comment: How about this: `using SimpleCall = void(*)(void*); std::vector<void*> modules_; std::vector<SimpleCall> dos_; template <typename Module> void add(Module& module) { modules_.push_back(&module); dos_.push_back([](void* p) { static_cast<Module*>(p)->doSomething(); }); }` This relies on the fact that a captureless lambda is convertible to a plan function pointer. A direct function call is as fast as this is gonna get, I don't see how you can do better. You call this as `dos_[0](modules_[0]);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you very much. With appropriate optimization this might work pretty well. I'll still have to benchmark it to be sure but it's the best solution so far. Generally I think I have to make a bit of a trade-off between abstraction and efficiency. The only way for it to be static polymorphism is if the respective modules are being passed as arguments in `System`. This of course would enable perfect efficiency but it's pretty ugly to handle.